# Send Google Home data to Splunk

Tags: splunk, google-home

I'm trying to send data generated by a Google Home mesh network to a Splunk instance. I'd especially like to capture which devices are connected to which points throughout the day. This information is available in the app, but does not seem to be able to be streamed to a centralized logging platform. Is there a way I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods of ingesting google cloud data supported by splunk.

--**Push-based method** : data is sent to a Splunk HTTP Event Collector (HEC) through a pub/sub to Splunk dataflow job.

--**Pull-based method**: data is fetched from the Google Cloud APIs through the Splunk Add-on for Google Cloud Platform.

It is generally recommended that you use the push-based method to ingest Google Cloud data in Splunk. Only in certain cases it is recommended to use the pull based method to ingest Google Cloud data into Splunk. These circumstances are as follows:
--Your Splunk deployment does not offer a Splunk HEC endpoint.
--Your log volume is low.
--You want to pull Cloud Monitoring metrics, Cloud Storage objects, or low-volume logs.
--You are already managing one or more Splunk heavy forwarders or are using a hosted Inputs Data Manger for Splunk Cloud.

```
More information as how to work around with the setup part and working around with this
problem can be found in the following link :

    https://cloud.google.com/architecture/exporting-stackdriver-logging-for-splunk
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm talking about Google Home router wifi data, not Google Cloud data.